# Rsync - Include Only One Folder

Tags: rsync

I have several folders inside a folder named "parent". Namely "childone", "childtwo", "childthree", as well as several files. I wish to rsync only "child three", along with whatever it contains, and absolutely nothing else. I tried several things, along the line of :

```
rsync -z --update --delete --recursive --verbose --delete-excluded --include='/***/childthree' --exclude='/*' /var/www/various/ root@some.domain.com:/home/backup/
```

but i can not find the proper combination of "includes" and "excludes".

Please assist.

Comment: do you know the path to parent?

Comment: `rsync [options] /var/www/various/rest/of/path/to/parent/childthree [dest]:/home/backup/rest/of/path/to/parent/` ?

Comment: `( cd /var/www/various; rsync [options] --relative rest/of/path/to/parent/childthree [dest]:/home/backup )` ?

Comment: I realize now that i have not asked properly. I apologize for this. So, here is a more precise way to put it: i need to drill down a directory structure, and rsync all possible instances of a specific folder name, along with the contents of these instances, and exclude everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily exclude **files** that are outside the desired tree but it is not so easy to exclude **directories**.

Consider this structure:

```
bash$ mkdir -p src/a/b{/c,}/p/{1,2,3} src/a/b/e dst
bash$ find src | xargs -I@ touch @/f
bash$ mkdir -p src/a/b/p/3/d
bash$ find src | sort
src
src/a
src/a/b
src/a/b/c
src/a/b/c/f
src/a/b/c/p
src/a/b/c/p/1
src/a/b/c/p/1/f
src/a/b/c/p/2
src/a/b/c/p/2/f
src/a/b/c/p/3
src/a/b/c/p/3/f
src/a/b/c/p/f
src/a/b/e
src/a/b/e/f
src/a/b/f
src/a/b/p
src/a/b/p/1
src/a/b/p/1/f
src/a/b/p/2
src/a/b/p/2/f
src/a/b/p/3
src/a/b/p/3/d
src/a/b/p/3/f
src/a/b/p/f
src/a/f
src/f
bash$
```

You can do:

```
bash$ rsync -n -ir \
              --include '/**/p/3/**' \
              --include '/**/p/3/' \
              --exclude '/**/p/**' \
              --include '/**/' \
              --exclude '/**' \
          src/ dst
cd+++++++++ a/
cd+++++++++ a/b/
cd+++++++++ a/b/c/
cd+++++++++ a/b/c/p/
cd+++++++++ a/b/c/p/3/
>f+++++++++ a/b/c/p/3/f
cd+++++++++ a/b/e/
cd+++++++++ a/b/p/
cd+++++++++ a/b/p/3/
>f+++++++++ a/b/p/3/f
cd+++++++++ a/b/p/3/d/
bash$
```

but notice that `a/b/e` is included in the result.

The reason is that unless rsync knows the full paths to the `p` directories, it has to be told to search down all possible branches from the root until it finds them, even branches that do not ultimately match.

If we elide the `--include '/**/'` rule, `p` will never be found:

```
bash$ rsync -n -ir \
              --include '/**/p/3/**' \
              --include '/**/p/3/' \
              --exclude '/**/p/**' \
              --exclude '/**' \
          src/ dst
bash$
```

If you need to exclude these other directories, then using `--prune-empty-dirs` is possible but this will also remove empty directories like `a/b/p/3/d`.

Alternatively, I think you need to specify the full path to the parent without wildcards. I'm not sure how to do this with rsync alone. However, you could generate the paths in advance and then feed them in.

For example:

```
bash$ ( cd src/; find . -type d -path '*/p/3' ) |
      awk '
          BEGIN { FS = OFS = "/" }
          {
              $1 = ""
              print $0 "/**"
              do { print $0 "/" } while( --NF > 1 )
          }
      ' |
      sort -u >includes
bash$ cat includes
/a/
/a/b/
/a/b/c/
/a/b/c/p/
/a/b/c/p/3/
/a/b/c/p/3/**
/a/b/p/
/a/b/p/3/
/a/b/p/3/**
bash$
```

Then:

```
bash$ rsync -n -ir \
              --include-from includes \
              --exclude '/**' \
          src/ dst
cd+++++++++ a/
cd+++++++++ a/b/
cd+++++++++ a/b/c/
cd+++++++++ a/b/c/p/
cd+++++++++ a/b/c/p/3/
>f+++++++++ a/b/c/p/3/f
cd+++++++++ a/b/p/
cd+++++++++ a/b/p/3/
>f+++++++++ a/b/p/3/f
cd+++++++++ a/b/p/3/d/
bash$
```

If paths could contain special characters like newline and you have GNU utilities, substitute above:

- `find ... -print0`
- `gawk 'BEGIN { RS = ORS = "\0"; ...'`
- `sort -uz`
- `rsync --from0 ...`